# How to pass an object from a view based on checkboxes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

i was wondering if its possible to pass an object based on a checkbox selection. Ill explain myself: If there is a selected value, that really means that I need to pass the object that the selection represents in order to use it.

I have this code in my view:

```
<% foreach (var _client in ViewData["channels"] as List<DigiTV.Models.CANAL>) { %>
   <%= Html.CheckBox(_client.NOM_CANAL) %> <%= Html.Encode(_client.NOM_CANAL) %> <br />
<% } %>
```

As you can see, I have a list of the object type that I want to pass to the controller (List)

Do someone has any suggestions?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would very strongly recommend you using view models, strongly typed views and editor templates.

So as always start by defining a view model which will contain all the necessary data your view might need:

```
public class CanalViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new[]
        {
            new CanalViewModel { Name = "canal 1", Selected = false },
            new CanalViewModel { Name = "canal 2", Selected = true },
            new CanalViewModel { Name = "canal 3", Selected = false },
            new CanalViewModel { Name = "canal 4", Selected = false },
        };

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<CanalViewModel> model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and next comes the `~/Views/Home/Index.aspx` view:

```
<%@ Page 
    Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<AppName.Models.CanalViewModel>>" 
%>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%= Html.EditorForModel() %>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
<% } %>
```

and finally you will need an editor template for a canal which will be executed for each element in the model (`~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/CanalViewModel.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<AppName.Models.CanalViewModel>" 
%>

<div>
    <%= Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Name) %>
    <%= Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Selected) %>
    <%= Html.LabelFor(x => x.Selected, Model.Name) %>
</div>
```

Now when you submit the form, inside the POST action you will get a list of all canals along with their selected property being depending on which checkboxes the user select.

As you can see we don't need any ViewData which will require you to perform some ugly casts in your views and you don't need to write any `foreach` loops in your views. Everything is handled automatically by the framework following well established conventions.

Answer (score 0):

you can make the using `javascript` by collecting all checked checkboxes values(comma separated) in a hidden field then read this values from your controller and split it.

```
<% foreach (var _client in ViewData["channels"] as List<DigiTV.Models.CANAL>) { %>
<%= Html.CheckBox(_client.NOM_CANAL) %> <%= Html.Encode(_client.NOM_CANAL) %> <br />
<% } %>
 <%=Html.HiddenField("AllValues")%>
```

javascript(I am using jquery)

```
   var allvalues='';
  $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(index){
       if($(this).is(':checked'))
       {
          allvalues+=$(this).val();
       }
   });
   $('#AllValues').val(allvalues);
```

in you controller

```
  public ActionResult MyAction(FormCollection form)
  {
     String[] AllValues = form["AllValues"].Split(",");
  }
```